# How do I reposition the Web View After the keyboard is gone?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, uiwebview, keyboard

I'm having a problem with a uiwebview in my app. Where the keyboard completely displaces the web content and i'm not able to move it back into place. There's also a problem when typing into the fields the webview bounces up and down vertically.

Before Keyboard

[Before http://www.306radio.ca/mobile/photo.PNG](http://www.306radio.ca/mobile/photo.PNG)

After Keyboard(Cant be scrolled down)(http://www.306radio.ca/mobile/chat)
[after http://www.306radio.ca/mobile/photo1.PNG](http://www.306radio.ca/mobile/photo1.PNG)

Answer (score 2):

Implement **`UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`** and **`UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`** and so you can do the Web-view reposition .

**Example:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];

}


- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   //align Web-view here
}
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   //align Web-view here
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```